# Is there a (fuller) transcript for Trump's recent quip about election officials being “communists” and “enemies of the state”?

Tags: united-states, election, donald-trump, rhetoric

AP recently reported [that](https://apnews.com/article/election-2020-joe-biden-donald-trump-pennsylvania-elections-93dbc7576bc75f7d4e2be1cdfedb03c7):

> Speaking to news crews gathered to watch the traditional holiday conversation with the military, Trump denounced officials in battleground states he’d lost as “communists” and “enemies of the state.”

Is there a fuller transcript context for these claims of Trump?

N.B., I was able to find a video of Trump's [speech](https://news.yahoo.com/trump-georgia-sec-state-raffensperger-235627574.html) in which he called the  Republican secretary of state of Georgia an "enemy of the people", which makes quite plausible the other quips, but that was apparently a different speech. The clip I found doesn't mention "communists".)

Answer (score 2):

Well, according to the [transcript](https://www.whitehouse.gov/briefings-statements/remarks-president-trump-thanksgiving-video-teleconference-members-military/) released by the White House of the "Remarks by President Trump During Thanksgiving Video Teleconference with Members of the Military", the only person he called "[probably] a communist" was one of the Democrats running for Senate in Georgia.

> But, anyway, going back to Georgia, just for a second: So I’ll be going there on Saturday night, and maybe I’ll go twice.  It’s very important that we win those races.  These are two great people.  I know them both very well.  They’re both great people.
>
> And I think the two people — you know, I beat — the one gentleman, he ran against a congressional candidate who was an excellent person, frankly.  And he didn’t even live in the right community, and that’s how we won.  So now I have to beat him again.  He lost as a congressman.  He was going for Congress, as you remember.  And now — against Karen.  And now — and now he’s running against David.  He doesn’t deserve to be there.  He’s a lightweight.
>
> And the other one is either a communist or socialist; I can’t figure that one out yet.  But he’s either a communist or a socialist.  Probably a communist.  This is not for Georgia.

The first Democrat mentioned by Trump there is no doubt [Jon Ossoff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon_Ossoff), so the second whom Trump labelled "probably a communist" has to be [Raphael Warnock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raphael_Warnock)
. As far as I can tell Warnock held no positions as an election official, the closest thing in his Wikipedia bio being that he "chaired the New Georgia Project, a nonpartisan organization focused on voter registration." So AP reporters probably misunderstood whom Trump was referring to as "probably a communist" or misunderstood his (Warnock's) role in the election process.

On the other hand, the White House transcript confirms Trump called Georgia's Secretary of State "an enemy of the people".

Comment: I'm not even sure that Trump even knows the difference between a communist and a socialist. But he probably thinks it makes him look smarter to equivocate between them.

Comment: Every so often I have to have a reality check.  The Republican party is actually quite a major party in the USA. It's not a tiny bunch of fruitcakes and loonies. Trump is an elected polititian with 45% of Americans thinking he is doing a good job.  That means if I watch some American reality show, there is a rougly 50% chance that the apparently rational people take this seriously. The transcript is not parody. America is a real place.  All these things I find so hard to believe.